# Configue IOS DHCP server to respond to Option 60 class

Tags: cisco-ios, dhcp

I have a number of small networks each with about half-a-dozen mostly-fixed hosts.  The routers on each network provide DHCP service for the occasional visiting engineer's laptop.  I am adding IP phones to some of the networks, and wish phones to be allocated particular group of IP addresses, without relying on the phone's ethernet addresses.

```
   +----intersite routing----+-------> many more sites
   |                         |
   R0                        R1
   |.1      192.168.0/24     |.1            192.168.1/24 
 ==+=====+=====+=====+==   ==+=====+=====+=====+=====+==
         |.64  |.65  |.145         |.64  |.65  |.145 |.146
         A     B   Phone           A     B   Phone Phone
```

I would like to do this with DHCP option 60, which the phones already send.

**How do you configure the IOS DHCP server to use the class information?**  For those familiar with ISC DHCPD, I'm after the equivalent of `match` ([ref](https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhcpdconf#CLIENT%20CLASSING)); Windows DHCP has Vendor Class and policy conditions ([ref](https://www.flomain.de/2019/05/dhcp-vendor-class-identifier-dhcp-option-60/)).

According to tcpdump, the phones send:

```
Vendor-Class Option 60, length 13: "Cisco SPA504G"
```

The command `ip dhcp class NAME` exists but I understand it to be all about option 82 classes and DHCP forwarding (per [RFC 3046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3046)), but I tried it nonetheless and without success.
Config I tried:

```
ip dhcp use class

ip dhcp pool ciscophones
 network 192.168.0.144 255.255.255.248
 class phones
  address range 192.168.0.145 192.168.0.147

ip dhcp class phones
   option 60 hex 436973636f2053504135303447     ! hex for ASCII "Cisco SPA504G"
```

I don't want to introduce VLANs if I can possibly help it, but I suppose that's another way to achieve my goal.

The routers are all Cisco 768VAE-K9 running various IOS typically 15.1.  The phones are all Cisco SPA504G running 7.6.2a.

Comment: On the surface, that looks like it should work. Maybe a few deep debugs are in order. (the IOS dhcpd is really stupid, bested only by the PIX/ASA)